# Fishbone stuck in throat

Tags: food, comfort

I have had a fishbone stuck in my throat for 4 months. I have visited a medical center for treatment but the doctor said there is no visible fishbone in my throat, but it's already been 4 months I still have this pain...it feels difficult  to breathe and pain on my left side of neck and shoulder... I tried almost all home remedies  but it doesn't  work...  could you give me some  effective  advice?

Comment: go to a better doctor. maybe do a x-ray (fishbone is bone afterall)  and get treated before an infection starts

Comment: Home and alternative medical treatments are not really within the spirit of this site. This problem is either medical, physiological, or psychological, but resolving this issue is outside the scope of *this* site.